# Angular package work locally but not work after deploy

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I use `ng2-jalali-date-picker` and `jalali-moment` in angular application.

my date picker work in local machine but i build and deploy application in server with this command : `ng build --prod` my components that contain date picker not loaded and my page not rendered.

I get this errors only in server:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'gregorian' of undefined
>
> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'hideInputContainer' of
>   undefined
>
> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'format' of undefined

I not any idea for this errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue with my angular app. 
I resolved it with this command, I hope it will work for you as well.

```
ng build --prod --aot=false --build-optimizer=false --no-progress
```